# Sharing view logic in Django

Tags: django, inheritance, view

I've begun diving into Django again and I'm having trouble finding the parallel to some common concepts from my life in C#. While using .NET MVC I very often find myself creating a base controller which will provide a base action implementation to take care of the type of stuff I want to do on every request, like retrieving user information, getting localization values.

Where I'm finding myself confused is how to do this in Django. I am getting more familiar with the MVT concept but I can't seem to find how to solve this scenario. I've looked at class based views and the generic views yet they didn't seem to work how I expected. What am I missing? How can i create default logic that each view will be instructed to run but not have to write it in each view method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is truly common for your whole site you use [middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs). If it is only common for some views, the way to go in my opinion is to create decorators for those views. I never use class-based views because I tend to keep views simple and put more logic into models, so I have no need for classes there.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. between the middleware and decorators I should be able to do everything I need.